# "= default" about constructor in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct Sale{
Sale () = default;//I got nothing about those cod
Sale(std::istream &input);
Sale(const std::string &s):book(s) {}
//and so on......
}
```

What did the second code mean?
Is that mean that doing nothing ?Or we must write those default code to tell the compiler we made a default constructor which doing nothing.
And what about the "= default" mean in the C++11?

Answer (score 0):

`= default` specifies `compiler` generted code for that function.